# meaning "upon which the system depends for"

Tags: meaning

In sentence "A system’s trust model defines the set of software and data upon which the system depends for correct enforcement of system security goals."
I don't understand the mean of "upon which the system depends for".any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Depends for* is not a phrasal verb here; the verb is just *depends* ["upon which the system depends"] and the *for* shows the reason that dependence is necessary ["for correct enforcement..."]

It's possible to re-order the sentence, which may make its description of the trust model's purpose clearer:

> The correct enforcement of system security goals depends on a set of software and data which is defined by the system's trust model.

Answer (score -2):

May be using preposition -on- instead of -upon- is more correct in this sentence.